# Why does Bombieri say this about Weil's Decomposition Theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Enrico Bombieri says this in his article "On Weil's Théorème de Décomposition" (American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 105, No. 2 (Apr., 1983), pp. 295-308, quoting p. 295)

> Consider for example a polynomial $p(x) = (x - m_1) ... (x - m_r)$
>   with roots distinct rational integers $m_1, .. ., m_r$; if we
>   specialize to a rational integer $n$, then $p(n)$ will factorize as a
>   product of the integers $n - m_i$ and moreover the G.C.D. of any two
>   such factors divides a fixed number, namely the product of $m_i - m_j$
>   for $i \neq j$. We see here that the integer $p(n)$ inherits a
>   factorization from the algebraic factorization of the function $p(x)$.
>   Weil's "Théorème de Décomposition" shows however that the
>   factorization of $p(n)$ has its origin in the decomposition of the
>   divisor of poles and zeros of the rational function $p(x)$ into prime
>   divisors, rather than the more obvious decomposition of $p(x)$ into
>   algebraic factors.

It seems that, for any function that can actually be given in the form $p(x)$ (thus any function on a domain that admits a global parameter $x$) the divisor of poles and zeros is not very different from an algebraic factorization.  Is he referring to that difference--that we do not need to know the specific function but only its poles and zeros?

@Vesselin Dimitrov's comment persuades me that Bombieri is saying something that Weil said more clearly in his thesis:

> An essential property of curves of genus 1 is that every rational
>   function of points n the curve can be decomposed into factors, each of
>   which is relevant to a single pole or a single zero of the function.
>   ... For general curves, such a decomposition is obviously not
>   possible. (p. 4)

Factorization generally makes no sense, while divisors do.

Or does Bombieri have some other point?

Comment: What you say in your last paragraph is exactly the point. Bombieri proves in this paper a theorem on the decomposition of the height $h(f(P))$ of a rational function evaluated on a point of an algebraic curve $C$, as the point $P \in C(\bar{K})$ varies. This result is trivial in the genus zero case, where one can simply use the algebraic factorization of the function. The gist of the theorem, and of Weil's theorem of decomposition, is that what really matters is the formal decomposition of the divisor $\mathrm{div}(f)$ into zero and poles.

Comment: In this form, the theorem has non-trivial applications, whereas the starting observation is completely trivial. His comment concerned the starting observation, in that what is truly essential about it is the divisor of zeros and poles of the function, not the accident that the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a PID.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov I believe you are right.  But then it would be better not to say the divisor matters more than the factorization.  It would be better to say factorization generally makes no sense -- while divisors do.